# ASP.NET Custom Validator and AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, customvalidator

I implemented a Custom Validator with AJAX, and It works fine:

**EDITED**. Add ASPX code

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="25em" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Insert" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnItemInserting="DetailsView_ItemInserting">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre *">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("nombre) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requireNombre" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNombre" ErrorMessage="El campo 'Nombre' no puede estar vacío." ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtNombre" ClientValidationFunction="validateNombre" ValidationGroup="DetailsGroup" Display="none" ErrorMessage="Introduzca un nombre diferente." runat="server"/>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Function AJAX:

```
        function validateNombre(src, args) {
        var isValid;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Nombre.aspx/ComprobarNombre",
            data: "{'nombre': '" + args.Value + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                isValid = msg.d;
            }
        });
        args.IsValid = isValid;
```

ComprobarNombre:
[WebMethod()]

```
    public static bool ComprobarNombre(string nombre)
        {
            /* SQLConnections... */

            if(...)
                 return false;
            else
                 return true;
        }
```

The problem is that the AJAX function is launched when every time I enter a value in the TextBox. I need that the function launch only when I click the button of the form.

Comment: Please share your aspx code , i want to see how textbox and button is  defined.

Comment: Now I share my aspx code

Answer (score -1):

1) Eliminate Custom validator
2) On button click call client side function validateNombre()
3) Fetch the textbox data inside the function
4) and pass it in as data parameter

Comment: $("#button").click( function(e)
           { e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Nombre.aspx/ComprobarNombre",
            data: "{'nombre': '" + $('#button').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                isValid = msg.d;
            }
        });
           }
        );

Comment: oops.. please try with id of the text box.