# Asp.NET user control date validation

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have created a user control which has 2 date controls(start date and end date). Now in my aspx page I am using the same user control twice with id as parent and child. Now i want that the dates in the child user control should be within the dates provided in the parent user control.

Please refer to the below code snippet, i want the dates selected to be within the range of the dates.

ASCX Page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EffectiveDate.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControlDemo.EffectiveDate" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptmanger1" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<table id="Table5" width="99%" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="20%">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Style="white-space: nowrap;" Text="Effective Start Date"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle">
            <asp:TextBox ID="attPrdStartdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/CalendarImage.png"
                Style="margin-bottom: -5px" />
            <ajaxtoolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender5" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="attPrdStartdate" ValidChars="1234567890/" />
            <ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="attPrdStartdate"
                PopupButtonID="Image3" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
            </ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="attPrdStartdate"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" ForeColor="Red" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
                Type="Date" Style="font-size: smaller">
            </asp:CompareValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="attPrdStartdate" Type="Date"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Dates out of range" ForeColor="Red" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle">
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Style="white-space: nowrap;" Text="Effective End Date"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle">
            <asp:TextBox ID="attPrdEnddate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:Label>
            <ajaxtoolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender6" runat="server"
                TargetControlID="attPrdEnddate" ValidChars="1234567890/" />
            <ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="attPrdEnddate"
                PopupButtonID="Image4" Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
            </ajaxtoolkit:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/CalendarImage.png"
                Style="margin-bottom: -5px" />
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="attPrdEnddate"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="attPrdStartdate"
                Operator="GreaterThan" Type="Date" Style="font-size: smaller">
            </asp:CompareValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="attPrdEnddate" Type="Date"
                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Dates out of range" ForeColor="Red" EnableClientScript="False"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="errlblBaseln" Text="" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="smaller"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ASCX Code Behind:

```
    namespace UserControlDemo
{
    public partial class EffectiveDate : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = endDate.ToShortDateString();
            RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = startDate.ToShortDateString();
            RangeValidator2.MaximumValue = endDate.ToShortDateString();
            RangeValidator2.MinimumValue = startDate.ToShortDateString();

        }
        private DateTime startDate;
        private DateTime endDate;

        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get { return startDate; }
            set { startDate = value; }
        }
        public DateTime EndDate
        {
            get { return endDate; }
            set { endDate = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

my aspx page:

```
 <uc:EfectiveDate ID="MyDates" runat="server" StartDate="01/01/2013" EndDate="12/12/2013" />
```

Comment: What kind of _date controls_? Please show us what you have. Also, what means parent/child in this context?

Comment: say suppose user selects start date as 1/1/2013 and end date as 12/12/2014.
So in the child user control user should be able to select date only between 1/1/2013 to 12/12/2014

Comment: Show your *.aspx markup code here

Comment: @insomnium_ i have added the aspx code in the above section

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this.

**Parent**

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Parent.ascx.cs" Inherits="StackOverFlow.Parent" %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Parent Start Date </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStartDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Parent End Date </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEndDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Child**

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Child.ascx.cs" Inherits="StackOverFlow.Child" %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Child Start Date </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStartDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Child End Date </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEndDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Your Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverFlow.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="p" Src="~/Parent.ascx" TagName="Parent" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="c" Src="~/Child.ascx" TagName="Child" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:Parent ID="parent" runat="server"></p:Parent>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <c:Child ID="child" runat="server"></c:Child>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <asp:Button Text="Compare" ID="btnCompare" runat="server" OnClick="btnCompare_Click" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtParentStartDate = (TextBox)parent.FindControl("txtStartDate");

        if (txtParentStartDate!=null)
        {
            DateTime dtParentStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtParentStartDate.Text.Trim());
        }

        //likewise get other dates and compare
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot for all ur effort. really appreciate. I modified the question, please have a look and suggest. I am trying to achieve this with the range validator.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal try using Custom validator instead of using Range validator. pls refer to this http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

Comment: Thanks will try that, but is there no way we can do using range, cos date type is supported in range and i want my dates to be within a particular range.

Comment: I tried the custom validator but the problem here is it is firing only when there is a postback in the server side. I need something which happens dynamically as and when my date is selected, just the way compare validator is working.

Comment: Try using Custom validator with a Ajax call. Have a look at here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162742/asp-net-custom-validator-and-ajax